# Add .so as php extension

Tags: php, dll, swig, php-extension, shared-objects

I have a .so file generated with SWIG. I would like use the functions defined there as a php extension. 
How do I add them as a php extension?

I added the .so to the extensions directory, and in php.ini added a line: "extension=example.so", then restarted apache.

Still when I run: `php -d "extension=example.so" -m`, it does not appear as an extension, and says: 
`"Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/...../example.so. cannot open shared object file: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0"`

Yet, permissions are 777

Permisions

[image: permissions]

PHP .so folder

[image: extensions folder]

php.ini file

[image: php.ini file]
[image]

checking for extension
[[image: checking for extension[5]]

Extension "example.so" not there.

Comment: is your extension_dir correct? is command-line php using the right php.ini?

Comment: 1. it is in the correct directory.
2. I added the extension to the /cli/ php.ini.

I just noticed, php -d "extension=xxxxx.so, says:
Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/...../xxxxx.so. cannot open shared object file: Permissino denied in Unknown on line 0

Comment: modify the permissions of your .so then :) `chmod 755 {so}`

Comment: What about the directory it's in?

Comment: @ also set to 777. I added pictures to show the state of affairs

Answer (score 5):

Solved by adding the full path of the .so to the php.ini

```
extension=/full/path/to/so/example.so
```

Therefore, adding the .so to the php extensions folder is unnecessary. The .so may reside in any directory.