# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function PDFNet_Initialize

Tags: php, pdftron

I am trying to run PDFTron for php following the [instructions](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/php/get-started/integration/mac/).
However, when called: `PDFNet::Initialize();` i'm getting an error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function PDFNet_Initialize() in .../PDFNetPHP_core.php
```

I assume that `PDFNet_Initialize` is part of extension because i can't see declaration in `PDFNetPHP_core.php` file

I setup exenstion `PDFNetPHP.so` and `enable_dl = on` in php.ini. Also when i run test in `PDFNetWrappers/Samples/AddImageTest/PHP` then it's looks ok:

```
PDFNet is running in demo mode.
Permission: write
Done. Result saved in addimage.pdf...<br />
```

when i run `php -m` module `PDFNetPHP` is on list

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If the sample code is working on your end, it's likely that your project is unable to find the `libPDFNetC.so`shared library. The `RunTest.sh` in the `AddImageTest` sample sets the following environment variable:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../../../PDFNetC/Lib
```

You might need to add the .so explicitly, or at least put the .so in a folder that PHP will load .so files from. See your PHP documentation. Please also see the following post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35442777/3761687

Comment: Path to .so file is correct, if it were wrong then command ```php --ini``` would throw an exception for module